# iPhone one title for all view controllers

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, title

I have an app with tab bar controller (with 4 views controller) and it contains a navigation controller. All of this was create programmatically.
My question:
Is there a way how to set one navigation bar title for all view controllers ? For example: When i switch tabs, title is the same. Ideal solution for me is set title in app delegate file. Thanks a lot

Comment: This probably is not a good question. You have navigation-controller to which you `setTitle` to identify each tab from your tabbar-controller. If you want to give same name to navigation bar from all tabs, then why r u choosing tabbar-controller?

Comment: Because my app has 4 different tabs and I will use navigation bar title for showing actual gps speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there will be exactly 4 views controller, just do `self.title = @"your title";` If you want to change "your title" once and have them all changed, just create a static global or use plist. And put the code under `viewDidAppear` so that it refreshes every time. No need to do anything too complex :)

Comment: I will change this title from "location manager" method (didUpdateToLocation ...) When location was change, update title with actual speed. My "location manager" functions are in app delegate so I need set title from this "didUpdateToLocation" method. This is what I want

Comment: Well, when your method `didUpdateToLocation` gets called, just set your global `globalTitle = @"my location";`( *my location is whatever you need your title to be* ) Then update the current page `self.title = globalTitle;`. Profit?

Answer (score 2):

For all of you, I think you want to put a log there, and it is to set an image file as the tab bar sub view and set the heights of the view controllers less the tab bar image as

```
UIImageView *navImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_LOGO]];
//[navImage setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 21)];
[navImage setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 21)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview: navImage];
[navImage release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a very basic subclass of `UIViewController` and set its title. Then, just have your other `UIViewController` subclasses inherit from this base class instead of directly from `UIViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this (i don't have access to Xcode atm so please debug it first):

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[tabBarController viewControllers] count]; i++) {
    [tabBarController objectAtIndex:i].title = @"This is the title";
}
```